# How can I read an option field from a SELECT?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a `select` named `telefoonnummer`

If somebody choses `gsm` then I want jQuery to know that the person pressed `gsm` by alerting `Ok`. I think I'm wrong with changed?

This is my code.

```
<select id="telefoonnummer">
<option value="gsm">Mobiele Telefoon</option>
<option value="huistelefoon">Huistelefoon</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#telefoonnummer').change(function () {
    if ($('#gsm:selected')) {
        alert('ok');
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var phone = $('#tel');
    $('#telefoonnummer').on('change', function () {
        var jValue = $(this).val();
        if ('gsm' === jValue) {
            if (9 != phone.val().length) {
                alert('error');
            }
        } else {
            if (10 != phone.val().length) {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7zs4pfjt/

Comment: That's a good start already! 
Now i want to know how do i put an if in it so if anybody clicks "gsm" this will happen and if anybody clicks "huistelefoon" other things happen.
Really appreciate your responding!

Comment: Nice it works! I'm only using jQuery for this so i didn't have a clue... .
Can you do one more thing for me? 
If ('gsm' ===jValue){ it must check if this input type is required, how do i do that? That is my last question!<input type="tel" name="input[]" id="tel">

Comment: So if my user clicks on gsm. He must enter something of 9 digits a phone number but if he clicks on huistelefoon he must enter something of 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Now you checked is element with id gsm is selected. It's not cause it's not exist (none element have that id).

Better will be checking if pressed option have value "gsm" :

```
$('#telefoonnummer').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "gsm" ) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pggpLgr6/